# TCP/IP Subnet Masking

Tags: subnet

I have a small confusion. I have watched an example on youtube on subnetting. It takes the Network IP 168.173.70.134 /29.

As I know, if we look at the 168, it is the rage 128 - 191, hence falls in Class B. But if we consider /29 it falls in the Class C.

Please someone enlighten me on this confusion :/

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and ignore everything you've ever heard about class A B and C networks.  It's an obsolete idea and will just make learning subnetting harder for you.

Comment: How  do you get the IP address of three subnets from a network ID 172.10.0.0 /19 ? and the range also?

Comment: Look at the duplicate question for an explanation.  If you still don't understand, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original address 168.173.70.134/29 is in [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), hence I'd assume classless routing.

In most practical cases Classes can be considered obsolete.

There are some edge cases, like RIPv1, for example, doesn't have support for variable length subnet masks. That said, I'd not expect to run into RIPv1 in any production network.